# nsurlsession ios 13 cellular Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios13

```
    NSString *dataUrl = @"https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    configuration.waitsForConnectivity = YES;
    configuration.allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess = YES;
    configuration.allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = YES;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [session
      dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

We have old application which was developed in 2015, it have many old code. On iOS 13, unfortunately on CELLULAR all NSURLSession requests (not only to our server but to any server) fails with error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x280526af0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={NSURLErrorNetworkUnavailableReasonKey=1, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSURLErrorNetworkUnavailableReasonKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.
```

Where NSURLErrorNetworkUnavailableReasonKey=1 is URLError.NetworkUnavailableReason.expensive

NSURLConnection requests are fine (except of deprecation warning)

What global setting, or at least local setting I should turn on, to make successful request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 7 hours of investigation I found that the problem was with library CCInfiniteScrolling (github.com/ziryanov/CCInfiniteScrolling). The problem with NSObject category and bad runtime coding: NSObject+DProperty.m. We rewrite all to object_associations and all works fine.

Comment: Can you push a request merge for  the project (github.com/ziryanov/CCInfiniteScrolling)  with your changes?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But after change the lib for the @AndreyBaskakov, it doesn't work. What was the problem with the the library? Maybe another one have the same issue.

Comment: What is not working? (in my project all works fine) You can rewrite by yourself using objc_setAssociatedObject it is not very difficult.